# HIVE Select as with Concat not working

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this query

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (enddate is NULL) THEN "Current" ELSE CONCAT(
    to_date(from_unixtime(startdate * 24 * 60 * 60)),
    ' - ',
    to_date(from_unixtime(enddate * 24 * 60 * 60))
  ) END as Current
FROM
  table
```

I'm getting this error `cannot recognize input near 'as' 'Current' ',' in selection target` but when I take out `as Current` out it works. I just want to alter the column name and not have it displayed `_c1` or something like that.

Comment: extraneous `,`...

Comment: My bad I copied and deleted the extra fields. I deleted the `,` and it's still not working

Comment: `current` is a reserved keyword. use a different alias instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current is a keyword in Hive, you need to change your alias or declare it using graves (`) as follow

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (enddate is NULL) THEN "Current" ELSE CONCAT(
to_date(from_unixtime(12 * 24 * 60 * 60)),
' - ',
to_date(from_unixtime(12 * 24 * 60 * 60))
) END as `Current`
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**current** is the reserved keyword in hive so if you have any column name which is matching with any of he reserved keyword in hive then you need to enclose that column with ``(back-tick).